# Destructor that deallocate dynamically allocated char array

Tags: c++

I need to write a destructor to deallocate the char array, but I always get this error message "pointer being freed was not allocated". It looks like I delete the location more than once, so I try to check if the char pointer is NULL, but it still doesn't work. Please help.
Note that: house object is a member data of another class.

```
class House {
private:
    char * location;
public:
    House();
    ~House();

House::House() {
    location = NULL
}

int House::create_house(char init_location[100]) {
    location = new char [strlen(init_location) + 1];
    strcpy(location, init_location);
    return 1;
}

House::~House() {
    if (location) {
        delete [] location;
        location = NULL;
    }
}
```

Edit: I added the constructor and the function showing how my location is allocated.

Comment: *"so I try to check if the char pointer is NULL, but it still doesn't work"* Do you set it to `NULL` anywhere before doing the `if (location)` check?

Comment: Please add code that how the `location` was allocated ?

Comment: My psychic powers suggest `location` is not getting initialized to `nullptr` in constructor.

Comment: `if (ptr) delete ptr;` is superfluous. `delete` supports `nullptr` argument, which resolves as noop. Also, assigning a valut to a non-static (non-reference) member variable, such as `location`, in a destructor does not make sense.

Comment: Sounds a lot like [rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) violation to me. Like, a lot a lot.

Comment: Please add more code.

Comment: please read about [mcve]. The code you posted is not sufficient to reproduce the error. It is just a class definition (a broken one, though that alone will not get you a runtime error). I edited my answer accordingly, but please next time make sure your question contains enough to reproduce the error

Answer (score 2):

> pointer being freed was not allocated

In the code you show indeed you do not allocate anything. `location` is just a pointer, there is nothing that could be deleted. You shall only call `delete` on a pointer to an instance that was acllocated via `new`.

Use a `std::string` instead, forget about `new` and `delete` and spend your time on the important things.

**...**

The question has been edited in the meanwhile. The posted code is still missing pieces that would be required to reproduce the error, and as I am unsure what exactly is left out too the only thing to add is that you are most likely violating the [rule of 0/3/5](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). The reason mentioned above for the error is still the same: You are trying to `delete` something where there is nothing (or something that has already been deleted). And my suggestion is still the same: use `std::string`.